# Share globals between modules with "from module import x" - is it possible?

Tags: python

Sorry, globals in Python makes me crazy. I read the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) for solution to share globals between modules. It works fine. But the problem is, that I don't want to write module prefix for globals in my program! The whole idea was that one module prepeares many short-named global shortcuts, and I want to use those shortcuts in another module without any module prefix, cause they are SHORTcuts!

```
#config.py:
x = 0   # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting

#mod.py:
import config
config.x = 1

#main.py:
import config
import mod
print config.x # outputs 1, as desired
```

So this works fine, but as soon as we modify mod.py to

```
from config import x
print 'mod.py:', x
x = 1
print 'mod.py:', x
```

Output becomes

```
mod.py: 0
mod.py: 1
0
```

So if I got it well, global from module config is cloned to global of module mod, so it becomes 2 different objects? But are there any solution that 2 modules can operate SAME object under SAME SHORTcut without explicit module name specification?

Comment: "But the problem is, that I don't want to write module prefix for globals in my program!" Then you can't. Python only has module-level "globals", not true global variables (which is a *good thing*). Unless the *object* is mutable, you cannot share state between these variables, they are in *different namespaces*. Anyway, you really shouldn't be using `from module import *`. All that does is "take every variable in the namespace of module and assign it to a variable with the same name in this module". The *objects* are the same, the *variables* are different.

Comment: why are you using `globals` ? they don't scale well, they are messy, and almost anything you want to do with `globals` you can do better and clearer with a different method

Comment: I am using globals just for convenience. I'd like to initialize many objects through many shortcuts, and I want to avoid to type something like init(self.f[1], self.b[1]) etc, but want just init(f[1], b[1]), which is much clearer in my context. My initialization procedures are informed about existence of shortcuts and those shortcuts are initialized by clear decorators. So I can easily archive my goal by putting the initialization of those shortcuts (as well as decorator definition) in single file together with init procedures, so all I want is just split this file into 2 ! But I can't!

Comment: Yes, Python variables fundamentally do not behave the way you want them to.

Comment: So the only way as I see is to write module local decorator warper, which will pass "local module-wide global" namespace to decorator in another module, and it will modify it directly. Python is a terrible power!